# Problems funding Ethereum Wallet

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Tried making three separate transactions from two separate wallets (Coinme and Coinbase) each in relatively small amounts (less than $50) to fund my Ethereum Wallet 8.0 for Mac. None have appeared after approximately 15 hours.

Earlier, in test mode on another machine (Ethereum Wallet 8.0) was able to mine 3000 ETH, but the funds disappeared when I quit and restarted the app. Since then, attempts to mine in test mode have not been successful.

Both wallets use Geth node.

Double-checked all addresses each time before sending.

Would anyone recommend to switching to Ethereum Wallet 9.0? Or am I better off just using the CLI tools?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what Ethereum wallet you are using, but to run a full node you can download the Mist wallet created by the Ethereum Foundation. https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases

You can also use MyEtherWallet: https://www.myetherwallet.com which is an web based wallet which requires zero syncing to be able to send and receive ether, and is probably the most user friendly offering. I would suggest you use this.

Follow up to this question with the exact wallet have downloaded, so that we can try and retrieve your coins and put them in your new wallet.